# LinearLayout in Android Studio not Cooperating

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

So, recently I just purchased the Big Nerd Ranch Guide to Android programming and am stuck on the very first section of code. The second LinearLayout is supposed to fall below the TextView widget, but for some reason is refusing to and is shoving the second LinearLayout to the side of the text allowing for only one of the buttons to be available. I have tried changing the api to different versions of Android all to no avail, and the forum for bignerdranch.com is filled with spam bots with very few questions actually being answered.
  Long story short I just need to figure out a way to move the second LinearLayout below the TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientaion="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="24dp"
            android:text="@string/question_text" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/true_button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/false_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinearLayout` defaults to `horizontal` orientation. You have misspelled `orientation`: you have `android:orientaion` and mistyped attributes are ignored at runtime (although Android Studio should have complained).

Answer (score 0):

**Use below xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:orientaion="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```